# PHP: OOP Relationship

Tags: php

I have 2 classes: Users & Courses.

Users will have a one_to_many relationship with courses. Once a user logs in, what's the best way to display all of their courses? Should I create a function under Users that is called getAllCoursesByUser or should I create it under Courses? I'm confused as to where to place these types of functions.

Comment: See: [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as the logic makes sense to the person writing the code (i.e. you). Me personally would put it in the Users class as there wouldn't be a relationship without the user and the courses would exist without the user anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$db = /* database connection */;

$id      = 42;
$user    = User::getById($db, $id);
$courses = Course::getAllByUser($db, $user);
```

If you are able to access courses from the user directly, that only creates IMO unnecessary coupling between the `User` and `Course` class. But you can really do it either way.

Answer (score 4):

Place the function in the class where the data is "calculating" from.  That being said, if you have a user and you want to learn all the courses the user has, put the function in User, called getAllCoursesByUser.  It will return an array of Courses.  If you want all the Users that have a specific course, put it in Courses and call it getAllUsersByCourse.

As Duniyadnd said, it is really up to you.  As long as you clearly understand it it can be considered good code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather place this in Users part, as too look from more humanistic side - every single man has many courses, but courses can't have men inside it (only from humanistic point of view).
Of course you may want to accomplish a task which requires even both of functions to exist.. What's your point to accomplish?